# How to use Observable.from(Future)?

Tags: rx-java

I'm learning RxJava on Android. I want to use it with networking, so I can't do stuff on main thread.

I have the following code:

```java
final String RXTAG = "Rx";
Log.d(RXTAG, "Starting Rx experiment");

final FutureTask<String> future = new FutureTask<>(new Callable<String>() {
    @Override
    public String call() throws InterruptedException {
        Log.d(RXTAG, "Callable called on thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        Utils.assertNotUIThread();
        Thread.sleep(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(1)); // Simulates network latency
        return "hello";
    }
});

Observable.from(future, Schedulers.io()).timeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS).subscribe(
        new Action1<String>() {
            @Override
            public void call(final String s) {
                Log.d(RXTAG, "Next " + s);
            }
        },
        new Action1<Throwable>() {
            @Override
            public void call(final Throwable throwable) {
                Log.w(RXTAG, throwable);
            }
        },
        new Action0() {
            @Override
            public void call() {
                Log.d(RXTAG, "Completed");
            }
        }
);
```

But it ends with `TimeoutException` after 5 secunds and the *Callable called* log is never showed. What's wrong, and how to make it work?

Comment: maybe you should use Vertx logger 'io.vertx.core.logging.Logger;' for log message to showed.

Comment: It's not logger problem. The initial log is shown, and also the log with error. And i if I use `Observable.just()`, also the Next log is shown.

Comment: sorry, I am wrong with vertx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to run the `Future` yourself. But un fortunately, it results in running the `Callable` on main thread, or you have to use `Executor`.

Instead, I come with the following solution:

```java
// Extract Callable from FutureTask

Single.fromCallable(callable).timeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).subscribe(
    new Action1<String>() {
        @Override
        public void call(final String s) {
            Log.d(RXTAG, "Success " + s);
        }
    },
    new Action1<Throwable>() {
        @Override
        public void call(final Throwable throwable) {
            Log.w(RXTAG, throwable);
        }
    }
);
```

And now it works as expected:

```
07-29 13:41:26.516 D/Rx: Starting Rx experiment
07-29 13:41:26.547 D/Rx: Callable called on thread RxIoScheduler-2
07-29 13:41:27.550 D/Rx: Success hello
```

Comment: To beginners, I suggest they familiarize themselves with the available methods in `Observable` and `Single` - even if you just read their names. Most operators are named in a way to match typical language used to express a required functionality.

Answer (score 2):

try adding below code before subscribe.

```
.doOnSubscribe(disposable -> future.run())
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
```

Rxjava2 code:

```
Observable.fromFuture(future, Schedulers.io())
.doOnSubscribe(disposable -> future.run())
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.subscribe(someConsumer()).
```

runs well.