# How to fix bug with a class that writes to excel in Java

Tags: java, mongodb, java-stream, export-to-excel

I currently want to fetch details of users in an asynchronous way and convert those details into an excel file.

Here is the method that fetches the details in batches from the db created in the repository.

```
public CompletableFuture<ArrayList<UserProfile>> fetchUserDetailsBatches(Bson filter){
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync( () -> {
            Bson projection = Projections.fields(Projections.exclude("roleGroup", "roles"));
            return this.userCollection.find(filter).projection(projection).skip(1).limit(1000).
                    into(new ArrayList<>());
        });
    }
```

Here is the class that converts to excel file. It was working pretty fine before now till when I was using Stream before I changed to CompleteFuture.

```
public static InputStream writeToExcel(CompletableFuture<ArrayList<UserProfile>> data) throws Exception {
        //Blank workbook
        try (XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook()) {

            //Create a blank sheet
            XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("userDetails report");

            AtomicInteger rowNum = new AtomicInteger(1);
            AtomicBoolean isHeaderSet = new AtomicBoolean(false);
            data.forEach(userProfile -> {
                if (!isHeaderSet.get()){
                    createHeader(userProfile, sheet);
                    isHeaderSet.set(true);
                }
                XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(rowNum.getAndIncrement());

                ObjectMapper mapObject = new ObjectMapper();
                Map<String, Object> mapObj = mapObject.convertValue(userProfile, Map.class);


                AtomicInteger cellNum = new AtomicInteger();
                mapObj.forEach((key, value) -> {
                    XSSFCell cell = row.createCell(cellNum.getAndIncrement());
                    cell.setCellValue(key);
                    if (value instanceof Integer)
                        cell.setCellValue((Integer) value);
                    else if (value instanceof BigDecimal)
                        cell.setCellValue(((BigDecimal) value).doubleValue());
                    else if (value instanceof Long)
                        cell.setCellValue((Long) value);
                    else cell.setCellValue(String.valueOf(value));

                });
            });
            try {
                //Write the workbook in file system
                ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                workbook.write(bos);
                byte[] barray = bos.toByteArray();
                InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(barray);
                log.info("userDetails.csv written successfully on disk.");
                return is;

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                throw new Exception(e.getMessage());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new Exception(e.getMessage());

        }
    }
```

This error here has been fixed by @Cremer. The file that id being returned here, I want it to be saved in S3 buckets and a url link will be sent to the email of the user.

This is what I was doing but not working.

```
public BaseResponse<Object> uploadDownloads(HttpServletRequest request, InputStream fileInputStream,
                                                FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail, String documentType){

        String url = " ";
        try {
            int contentLength = request.getContentLength();
            if (contentLength == -1 || contentLength > FILE_SIZE_MAX) {
                throw new Exception("File size must be less than 5mb");
            }
            String fileName = fileDetail.getFileName();
            int index = fileName.lastIndexOf('.');
            String extension = index > 0 ? fileName.substring(index) : "";

            final String unique_name = fileName + "_" + documentType + extension;
            final String filePath = String.format("file/%s", unique_name);

            url = awsFactory.putS3Object(filePath, fileInputStream, "csv/" + fileDetail.getFileName().substring(index + 1));

            return BaseResponse.<Object>builder()
                    .status(true)
                    .responseCode("00")
                    .message(SUCCESS)
                    .data(url)
                    .build();

        } catch (Exception ase) {
            ase.printStackTrace();
            return BaseResponse.<Object>builder()
                    .status(false)
                    .responseCode("96")
                    .message(ase.getMessage())
                    .data(null)
                    .build();
        }

    }
```

This is how the s3 buckets looks like

```
 public String putS3Object(String objectKey, InputStream inputStream, String contentType) throws IOException {
        try {

            awsCreds = AwsBasicCredentials.create(getAccessKey(), getSecretKey());

            Region region = Region.EU_WEST_2;
            S3Client s3 = S3Client.builder()
                    .region(region)
                    .credentialsProvider(StaticCredentialsProvider.create(awsCreds))
                    .build();

            PutObjectRequest objectRequest = PutObjectRequest.builder()
                    .bucket(bucketName)
                    .key(objectKey)
                    .contentDisposition(String.format("inline; filename:%s", objectKey))
                    .contentType(contentType)
                    .build();

            s3.putObject(objectRequest, RequestBody.fromBytes(inputStream.readAllBytes()));

            return String.valueOf(s3.utilities().getUrl(
                    GetUrlRequest.builder().bucket(bucketName).key(objectKey).region(region).build()));

        } catch (SdkServiceException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            log.info(e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }
```

This is how the controller looks like

```
@GET
    @Path("/uploadReport/")
    @Timed

    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response uploadDownloads( @Context final HttpServletRequest request,
    @NotNull final String id,@FormDataParam("file") final InputStream fileInputStream,
                               @FormDataParam("file") final FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail,
                               @FormDataParam("documentType") String documentType) {
//
//        log.info("this is the userId -> {}", id);

        return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(
                userProfileService.uploadDownloads(request, fileInputStream, fileDetail, documentType)
        ).build();

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wait for the Future(here your parameter data) to be loaded, you an do it [async](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38654826/how-to-use-observable-fromfuture) or you can just call data.get() and then start using '.foreach', it stops the current thread as long as it takes to complete the future.

Edit:
Just replace the lower method with this:

```
public static InputStream writeToExcel(CompletableFuture<ArrayList<UserProfile>> data) throws Exception {
    //Blank workbook
    try (XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook()) {

        //Create a blank sheet
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("userDetails report");

        AtomicInteger rowNum = new AtomicInteger(1);
        AtomicBoolean isHeaderSet = new AtomicBoolean(false);
        data.get().forEach(userProfile -> {
            if (!isHeaderSet.get()){
                createHeader(userProfile, sheet);
                isHeaderSet.set(true);
            }
            XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(rowNum.getAndIncrement());

            ObjectMapper mapObject = new ObjectMapper();
            Map<String, Object> mapObj = mapObject.convertValue(userProfile, Map.class);


            AtomicInteger cellNum = new AtomicInteger();
            mapObj.forEach((key, value) -> {
                XSSFCell cell = row.createCell(cellNum.getAndIncrement());
                cell.setCellValue(key);
                if (value instanceof Integer)
                    cell.setCellValue((Integer) value);
                else if (value instanceof BigDecimal)
                    cell.setCellValue(((BigDecimal) value).doubleValue());
                else if (value instanceof Long)
                    cell.setCellValue((Long) value);
                else cell.setCellValue(String.valueOf(value));

            });
        });
        try {
            //Write the workbook in file system
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            workbook.write(bos);
            byte[] barray = bos.toByteArray();
            InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(barray);
            log.info("userDetails.csv written successfully on disk.");
            return is;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new Exception(e.getMessage());
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new Exception(e.getMessage());

    }
}
```

Comment: I would really appreciate if you could explain further or probably use part of my code snippets as an illustration. Thanks!

Comment: I did it, as you can see I just put a .get() before the .foreach.

Comment: kindly check, I made some updates. How do I go about it please?

Comment: I see and do understand your updates but can you please send me detailed errors? I need a bit more context

Comment: I have been able to fix the updateI will probably update with another bug. Thanks